# Change the boot order with no option in UEFI settings

Tags: boot, multi-boot, uefi

I have got a Lenovo MIIX 310-ICR 2-in-1 with Windows 10 preinstalled. I installed Ubuntu on it, but to boot into Ubuntu I have to either restart while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> in Windows 10 to get to its boot list, or when turned off, hold <kbd>Power</kbd> and  <kbd>Volume +</kbd> until I see the UEFI boot list, and choose Ubuntu from there.

What I want is to make it boot from the Ubuntu partition **by default**, so then I could choose which OS to boot from `grub`. I do not mind using another boot manager like `rEFInd`, or none at all; since I want to uninstall Windows once I get this sorted out. Although I would prefer keeping `grub` just in case I screw up Ubuntu and need to switch kernels or boot in recovery mode easily.

I went to the UEFI settings to change the boot order, but there is no option for that, so I think the only way to do it is not going to be through the UEFI settings.

BIOS version: `1HCN44WW`

## UPDATE:

Output of `efibootmgr`:

```
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0003,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0002* rEFInd Boot Manager
Boot0003* ubuntu
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

Output of `sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI`:

```
Boot  Insyde  Microsoft  refind  tools  ubuntu
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution described in my first answer is valid in general cases, but it seems that InsydeH2O UEFIs may ignore boot order. Many laptop manufacturers use Insyde firmware, so many models are affected by this issue. Yours uses Insyde UEFI too, as indicated by the presence of `EFI/Insyde` directory on the EFI System Partition (ESP, mounted as `/boot/efi` under Linux).

[A question about similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/150174/129094) was asked on AskUbuntu. Its OP analysed how this UEFI looks for boot candidates on ESP. The order is:

1. `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/fwbootmgr.efi`
2. `EFI/*/grubx64.efi`
3. `EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi`

They have described their experiments and final setup [in their self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/150640/129094), so I won't repeat that knowledge here.

Keep in mind that Windows may not be able to properly restore from hibernation/hybrid shutdown after messing with its boot files, as noted by another user in a comment.

Note that you can access the ESP under Windows too by mounting it using the `diskpart` tool:

1. Launch `diskpart` by typing its name in the Start menu.
2. List partitions and find ESP: `list partition` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Look at partition labels and sizes, ESP will typically be under 600 MB.
3. Select ESP: `select partition <x>` (`<x>` is number from the previous list)
4. Mount the partition: `assign letter=Z`. A new drive Z: will appear.

Comment: Replacing `/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` with `/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` did it. Moving the original `bootmgfw.efi` up one directory made it so `rEFInd` can find it and boot Windows.

Answer (score 9):

In Ubuntu you can use `efibootmgr` to achieve this.

1. Open the Terminal.
2. Type `efibootmgr` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll see a list of available boot options. Each option will have a number. Numbers may not be sequential - don't worry, it's normal. Here's an example output:

   ```
   BootCurrent: 0000
   Timeout: 2 seconds
   BootOrder: 0001,0000
   Boot0000* ubuntu
   Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager
   ```
3. Figure out the boot order you'd like to use. For the example above, it would be `0,1` (because Ubuntu is 0 and Windows is 1). Most of the time only first number matters. The second one would be used if first one is unavailable.
4. Update boot order: `sudo efibootmgr --bootorder 0,1`

Comment: It completely ignored this, and booted straight into Windows like it's used to. Not overwritten/not saved, just ignored.

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's one of those faulty UEFI implementations. Please edit the question and add output of `efibootmgr` and `sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI`.