# Install grub with windows and linux already installed

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

First the machine only had Ubuntu 18.04, this operating system was installed on the ssd.
I wanted to dual boot with Windows 10, so I made a bootable usb and installed it on the HD. Everything I read said that installing windows would erase Ubuntu and I would need to start again from scratch, but that didn't happen. I can change the boot order in the BIOS and the computer boots from Ubuntu again!

This is really good because I don't want to install everything all over again, but I also don't want to mess around in the BIOS to switch OS.

Can I install a boot loader like grub to make the switch easier? I can't see how to install just the boot loader on it's own, all the instructions seem to assume you are installing another os.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/192703/666427 < for future readers; this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu always installs GRUB, so you already have it installed. It may not be aware of Windows, though. Use the command `sudo update-grub` to fix this. Then change the boot order either through UEFI setup or [from Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/a/1451250/194694). Done, you'll boot into GRUB by default with ability to boot either Ubuntu or Windows.

If you want to have a graphical boot menu, rEFInd is really nice.